# SQL Edition Downgrade Impact on Jobs

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, ssis-2014, downgrade

We’ve made a downgrade from Enterprise Evaluation Edition to Standard and we saw the overnight jobs all running much longer. These are ETL packages and stored procedures to load data from an application server to a DW server (which was also downgraded from Enterprise to Standard). All other settings haven't changed, including configuration and network etc.

It seems the performance took a hard hit, but we don't know where to start?

The downgrade was performed by a third-party vendor and steps are as suggested on the [MS SQLTips website](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3079/downgrade-from-sql-server-enterprise-edition-to-standard-edition/).

We didn't move to a new server, just reinstalled SQL Server; copy out and back in the sys databases. We've checked the scale limits, we have 16 cores and max memory set to 70G, DW size around 900G which all within the range of limit of Standard Edition. And I believe, the core engine is the same as Enterprise. We do not utilise any features in Scale and Performance box too. Configurations all the same as master db copied.

Comment: Is it a VM ? If so check how many sockets you have configured & check the SQL Server error log to see how many CPUs SQL Server is using.